# PANDAS reading dataframe from file properly

Tags: python, pandas

my file(text file) looks like:

```
 -1         1 2.99988E-02-4.93580E-17 4.28928E-17-2.01725E-16 4.57184E-18 1.54030E-16
 -1         2 2.99988E-02-4.93581E-17-3.85396E-17-2.02655E-16-4.41397E-17-2.23963E-16
 -1         3 2.99988E-02 2.47173E-17 4.28930E-17 1.60350E-16 5.28503E-17 1.53007E-16
...
```

i want to create a dataframe with header and index, so that it looks like:

```
  0 1          2            3          4            5           6   
0 1 2.99988E-02-4.62001E-17 3.51002E-17-1.90612E-16 1.52704E-17 1.41065E-16
1 2 2.99988E-02-4.62001E-17-2.81042E-17-1.88765E-16-3.45762E-17-2.06278E-16
...
```

i tried this but it didnt work out:

```
df = pd.read_table(file_dir, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

and

df = pd.read_table(file_dir, sep='s+', header=None)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `-` as your separator for some (but not all) of the example data cells? This would make the data harder to process as you also need `-` for the negative exponents

Comment: Otherwise, you probably need to add `names=list(range(7))` as a parameter to `pd.read_table()` -- see the pandas documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a delimited file, but a fixed widths one. It used to be a common format in the 80' when we used the Fortran IV language...

But it is still supported by pandas with the `read_fwf` function:

```
df = pd.read_fwf(file_dir, header=None, widths=(3,10) + 6 * (12,))
```

It should directly give:

```
     0    1         2  ...             5             6             7
0 -1.0  1.0  0.029999  ... -2.017250e-16  4.571840e-18  1.540300e-16
1 -1.0  2.0  0.029999  ... -2.026550e-16 -4.413970e-17 -2.239630e-16
2 -1.0  3.0  0.029999  ...  1.603500e-16  5.285030e-17  1.530070e-16
...
```

Comment: thank you very much it does work. yes its an output file from a programm written in fortran. whats the meaning of the last part of the code ...widths=(3,10) + 6 * (12,))? some kind of recognition for the numbers?

Comment: @pofi: it is the Pythonic way to build a tuple (kind of read only list) containing `3` and `10` followed by six `12`. Said differently it is a lazy way to write `(3, 10, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12)`

Comment: aaah ok so its a manually seperating at those points. nice technique appreciate Serge;)

Answer (score 0):

instead to read the file as table you can load it like csv on pandas. here is script and output.

```
with open('ejemplo.txt', 'r') as tabla:
    df = pd.read_csv(tabla, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you might need to add a space or two between numbers so that pandas can separate data well.

`data.txt`

```
 -1         1 2.99988E-02 -4.93580E-17  4.28928E-17 -2.01725E-16  4.57184E-18  1.54030E-16
 -1         2 2.99988E-02 -4.93581E-17 -3.85396E-17 -2.02655E-16 -4.41397E-17 -2.23963E-16
 -1         3 2.99988E-02  2.47173E-17  4.28930E-17  1.60350E-16  5.28503E-17  1.53007E-16
```

And then run

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=r'\s{1,}', engine='python', header=None)
df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

should achieve what you want...